# Remove git merge commit without conflict

Tags: git, merge, commit, rebase, conflict

Below is my git commit history:

```
HEAD
... +500 commits
A   4140759b
A   c5cf69a2
A   3e5282cb  ⎯┐   << Merge branch B
|   94936548    B
|   02a550ce    B   
A   5d09daa9  ⎯┤   << Pull request
|   afbe397b    B   << Merge branch A into B
|   74fe4f3c    B
|   86cdc993    B
|   223e1740    B
|   a7ea596a    B
|   0d4c36cf    B
A   2740d295    |
A   24437962    |
A   73725f04    |
A   90be4300    |
A   6b1720d6  ⎯┘
A   d65bf4bd
...
```

I want to remove B branch history and merge commit, and leave A branch history only.

But, they are very old commits, with hundreds of commits between the latest commits,
so `git rebase -i` command makes a lot of conflicts that I couldn't solve.

It doesn't matter if a few commits, between d65bf4bd and c5cf69a2, dropped.
However, recent commits, after c5cf69a2, should not be affected.

How can I completely remove B branch history, from history?

My expected result looks like this:

```
HEAD
... +500 commits
pick    A   4140759b
pick    A   c5cf69a2
[drop]  A   3e5282cb  ⎯┐   << Merge branch B
[drop]  |   94936548    B
[drop]  |   02a550ce    B   
[drop]  A   5d09daa9  ⎯┤   << Pull request
[drop]  |   afbe397b    B   << Merge branch A into B
[drop]  |   74fe4f3c    B
[drop]  |   86cdc993    B
[drop]  |   223e1740    B
[drop]  |   a7ea596a    B
[drop]  |   0d4c36cf    B
pick    A   2740d295    |
pick    A   24437962    |
pick    A   73725f04    |
pick    A   90be4300    |
pick    A   6b1720d6  ⎯┘
pick    A   d65bf4bd
...
```

Comment: Do you want to also remove _the changes brought in by `B`_ ? that is: actually drop the content of `3e5282cb Merge branch B` ? or do you want to squash the changes in `2740d295..3e5282cb` in one single commit ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, I want to remove the 3e5282cb merge commit. Actually, I don't know much about git history management, so I can't tell you exactly. It may be helpful to refer to the commit message, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycgto.png. The commits from 90be4300 to 2740d295 and the commits from 0d4c36cf to 86cdc993 are contextually identical. It is ideal to squash 2740d295..3e5282cb, so then c5cf69a2 commit would be right after 2740d295.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to squash together the history of branch B:

1. use `git replace` to create a commit, with the same end content but only one parent, *and* a replacement rule

```
git replace --graft [target commit] [the parent you want]
# with the hashes you provided:
git replace --graft 3e5282cb 2740d295
```

on your machine, `git log --oneline --graph` should already display a simplified history

2. to make this replacement rule permanent and actually rewrite the history, use `git filter-repo` or `git filter-branch`

```
git filter-repo --replace-refs delete-no-add

# or
git filter-branch --env-filter true
```

---

a note about `git filter-branch`: making the replacement permanent is actually a side effect of `git filter-branch [any command]`, you can use any subcommand (`--index-filter`, `--env-filter`, `--tree-filter` ...) and any scripted action as long as it makes `git filter-branch` go through. `--env-filter true` happens to be convenient, because `git` will not read or write any file on disk, and `true` has no side effects.

Comment: Thank you! It works well. all of commits from branch B removed on my history.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it *will* be painful if you go with rebase interactive... actually, why are you trying interactive? If the 2 merges of branch B are one after the other, then you should be able to pull it off like this:

```
git rebase --rebase-merges --onto 2740d295 3e5282cb HEAD
```

That should remove the commits from B *and* the 2 merge commits. It's not like you will not get conflicts.... you will still get conflicts but given that you are using `--rebase-merges` it *will* include the merges (though you might still have to solve conflicts in the merges) and other conflicts could be related to the changes you are *not* including from `B`.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. It is good suggestion, but it still makes a bunch of conflicts to me. I solved the problem with others help.